# Unable to run Grass GIS in Python?

Tags: python, grass-gis

I am trying to run Python code for Grass GIS from this [site](https://grasswiki.osgeo.org/wiki/GRASS_GIS_APIs)

Specifically, here is my code:

```
## Import libraries needed to call GRASS using Python
import grass.script as grass
from grass.script import core as grass
import grass.script as grass 
grass.run_command('g.region', raster='elevation')
```

But I am getting the following error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
CalledModuleError                         Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-13-2ea69f70ebcb> in <module>()
      7 from grass.script import core as grass
      8 import grass.script as grass
----> 9 grass.run_command('g.region', raster='elevation')

C:\Program Files\GRASS GIS 7.5.svn\etc\python\grass\script\core.pyc in run_command(*args, **kwargs)
    419     else:
    420         returncode = ps.wait()
--> 421     return handle_errors(returncode, returncode, args, kwargs)
    422 
    423 

C:\Program Files\GRASS GIS 7.5.svn\etc\python\grass\script\core.pyc in handle_errors(returncode, result, args, kwargs)
    330         args = make_command(*args, **kwargs)
    331         raise CalledModuleError(module=None, code=repr(args),
--> 332                                 returncode=returncode)
    333 
    334 def start_command(prog, flags=b"", overwrite=False, quiet=False,

CalledModuleError: Module run None ['g.region', 'raster=elevation'] ended with error
Process ended with non-zero return code 1. See errors in the (error) output.
```

Comment: what happens if you run the last two lines? (skipping the third)

Answer (score 1):

I tried your code, and I get the same result,
you have to do the def,

```
import grass.script as gscript



def main():
    gscript.run_command('g.region', flags='p')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```